# Sql server management studio 2008: what permissions are necessary to display table list?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS 2008, when I expand the tables folder, all i see is the "System Tables" folder.

In SSMS 2005, when I connect to the exact same database with same account, I expand the tables folder and see all my tables.  Has something changed with which tables are displayed by default?  Does it only show tables in the default schema by default?

Answer (score 0):

found that it was related to my user account not having select permssions on some SYS objects as well as select access to the owner of the tables